# How does p >>= f works in Parser instance?

Tags: parsing, haskell

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

instance Monad Parser where
    return a = Parser (\cs -> [(a,cs)])
    p >>= f = Parser (\cs -> concat [parse (f a) cs’ | (a,cs’) <- parse p cs])
```

There is an explanation on the [paper](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf)

> The (>>=) operator is a sequencing operator for parsers. Using a
>   deconstructor function for parsers defined by parse (Parser p) = p,
>   the parser p >>= f first applies the parser p to the argument string
>   cs to give a list of results of the form (a,cs’), where a is a value
>   and cs’ is a string. For each such pair, f a is a parser which is
>   applied to the string cs’. The result is a list of lists, which is
>   then concatenated to give the final list of results.

But this is still not clear. Can anyone explain it with some examples? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps before studying the `>>=` operator itself, do you understand the idea behind a parser wrapping a function of type `ByteString -> [(a, ByteString)]`?

Comment: The idea of `>>=` is to enable *exhaustive* searching a valid way to parse a string into an object. It is a bit related to the `>>=` of a list `[]`.

Comment: What is not clear?

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem  Yup, it is mentioned on the paper

Comment: @ Cubic Like how does p>>f first applies the parser p to the argument string cs? It skips all the things before the bar |.

Comment: @user8314628: The thing with the bar is *list comprehension*: https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension It does not "skip" the parts before the bar, the bar denotes the separation between the "yield" part, and the "generator" part.

Comment: ahhh, I thought it is an "or" symbol

Comment: @user8314628: in Haskell the "or" symbol is `||`: https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(%7C) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell a parser is an example of a `Monad`. Monads are actually a much broader topic than just parsers, but they actually make a good introduction to the concept. Here is how it works here.

In a parser you want to be able to recognise rules like (in BNF)

```
assignment ::= identifier "=" expression
```

In Haskell you would write it like this:

```
data Statement = 
    Assignment Identifier Expression
    | Block [Statement]  -- A block is a list of statements.
    | Conditional Expression Statement Statement
    | -- etc. 

identifier :: Parser Identifier  -- Implementation omitted.

literal :: String -> Parser ()   -- Implementation omitted.

expression :: Parser Expression   -- Implementation omitted.

assignment :: Parser Statement
assignment = do          -- Note the "do" here.
   ident <- identifier   
   literal "="          
   expr <- expression
   return (Assignment ident expr)   -- "return" doesn't mean what you think.
```

This captures the idea of a parser for assignments being a sequence of sub-parsers: first you parse the identifier, then you recognise the "=", then you parse the expression on the right hand side. Hopefully you can see how the BNF maps into the Haskell code.

The "do" syntax in Haskell is syntactic sugar for expressions that use the `>>=` operator (which is called "bind"). The `assignment` example above de-sugars into the following (approximately: there is stuff about pattern match failures that I am skipping over here)

```
assignment = 
    identifier >>= (\ident ->
        operator "=" >>= (\dummy ->
           expression >>= (\expression -> return (Assignment ident expr))))
```

Each `\` (called "lambda") introduces an anonymous function. The `>>=` operator takes two arguments. On the left hand side is some value wrapped up in the Parser monad. On the right hand side is a function that takes this value and returns a new wrapped value. The job of the bind operator is to unwrap the value on the left (which may involve doing some magic side effects) and pass it to the function on the right. In this case the magic side effects include consuming the input text.

Note how the binds and anonymous functions are nested in the de-sugared version. Each successive line in the "do" syntax translates into a new function inside the one for the previous line. That means that the last function has access to all the variables in all of the functions so far. Its a way of modelling a block of assignments in a pure functional language like Haskell.

I said in the comments that "return" doesn't mean what you think it means. In Haskell it is nothing to do with flow of control, it just wraps up a value in a monad (in this case `Parser`) without causing any side effects itself.

This particular parser generates lists of results. That is, rather than deciding on the One True Parse at every step, when it encounters something ambiguous it generates a list of results. The bind operator takes each of the results so far and passes it to the function on its right, which in turn may generate multiple results again. Or a parser may generate no results in which case that branch is abandoned. Hence each step starts with a list of results, and the next step gives a list of lists of results, which is then folded back into a flat list of results by the "concat" function.

The `Monad` class given in your question is part of the standard library. It happens that there are lots of useful functions that apply to all monads, so giving them a common interface works well. In the case of `Parser` the bind operator has the type

```
(>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
```

and `return` has the type

```
return :: a -> Parser a
```

Meditate on these types and the description I gave of what bind and return do, and you may achieve monadic enlightenment.