# How to create a newtype of parser?

Tags: haskell, newtype

```
newtype Parser a = PsrOf{
    -- | Function from input string to:
    --
    --   * Nothing, if failure (syntax error);
    --   * Just (unconsumed input, answer), if success.
    dePsr :: String -> Maybe (String, a)}
```

I want to create a newtype of Parser to see how it looks like.

I tried

```
*ParserLib> PsrOf{"hello"}
```

But it comes up with an error

```
<interactive>:5:7: error: parse error on input ‘"’
```

Comment: `PsrOf` expects a function, not a string. You are conflating parser construction with parser *application*. Assuming `f :: String -> Maybe (String, a)`, you would want something like `dePsr (PsrOf f) "hello"`.

Comment: The record syntax you are using only applies to modifying an *existing* parser. Something like `let oldParser = PsrOf someFunc in oldParser { dPsr = newFunc }`. (It doesn't really make sense for a type that wraps a single value. It's more for making a copy of a more complex object while changing one piece of it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already created the type. Now you want to create a *value* of that type. To do that, you need to call `PsrOf` with a value of type `String -> Maybe (String, a)`. For example:

```
newtype Parser a = PsrOf { dePsr :: String -> Maybe (String, a) }

get3 :: String -> Maybe (String, Int)
get3 ('3':xs) = Just (xs, 3)
get3 _ = Nothing  -- Any string, including the empty string, that doesn't start with '3'

get3P :: Parser Int
get3P = PsrOf get3
```

To actually use the parser, you need to extract the function before applying it to a string:

```
dePsr get3P "38" -- Just ("8", 3)
dePsr get3P ""   -- Nothing
dePsr get3P "hello" -- Nothing
```

Record syntax here is just used to simplify the definition of the type, instead of writing

```
newtype Parser a = PsrOf (String -> Maybe (String, a))
dePsr :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe (String, a)
dPsr (PsrOf f) = f
```

The rest of the uses for record syntax (pattern matching or making slightly modified copies of a value) don't really apply usefully to types that wrap a single value.

Comment: Your next job is to make a Monad instance for this type. You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987691/how-does-p-f-works-in-parser-instance/51989244#51989244

Comment: @PaulJohnson is it? A monad instance is useful, but not really necessary.

Comment: @Cubic How else are you going to code a sequence of sub-clauses like "assignment ::= identifier '=' expression"? Yes, you could create your own sequencing operator from scratch, but it would be a really dumb thing to do.